# Implementing ACPI function in UEFI

Tags: wmi, uefi, acpi

I'm trying to implement ACPI function that will run in UEFI that will respond to code similar to this:

```
'executes a WQL query 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Password where InstanceName='ACPI\\PNP0C14\\0_0'")
'modify the supervisor password
For Each objItem in colItems
     'execute the method and obtain the return status     
     objItem.SetPassword strInParamValue, strReturn Next
```

Which UEFI protocol/functions are needed to be implemented? please refer me to sample code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what would you like to development, it is built from BIOS. unless you got source code from project vendor. otherwise, you cannot change it. however, if you are application development. you can get mof to create self-application to do something.